# Query to extract all Paths from ExtensionSettings in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I need to extract a list of the paths that are in the ExtensionSettings field of the Subscriptions table in SSRS.  Does anyone have a script for that?

Answer (score 1):

I found a good script here:  http://www.andrewing.co.uk/parse-ssrs-subscriptions-table/

```
WITH S AS (
   SELECT TOP 1000
     [SubscriptionID],
     ExtensionSettings = cast(ExtensionSettings as xml)
   FROM [ReportServer].[dbo].[Subscriptions]
)
SELECT
  S.SubscriptionID,
  TransmissionMethod = CASE
 ExtensionSettings.value('(/ParameterValues/ParameterValue/Name)[1]', 'varchar(50)')
        WHEN 'TO' THEN 'Email'
        WHEN 'PATH' THEN 'File Share'
        ELSE 'Unknown' END,
  FileSharePath = ExtensionSettings.query('
        for $parameter in /ParameterValues/ParameterValue
        let $name := $parameter/Name
        let $value := $parameter/Value
        where $name = "PATH"
        return data($value)'),
  FileName = ExtensionSettings.query('
        for $parameter in /ParameterValues/ParameterValue
        let $name := $parameter/Name
        let $value := $parameter/Value
        where $name = "FILENAME"
        return data($value)'),
  RenderFormat = ExtensionSettings.query('
        for $parameter in /ParameterValues/ParameterValue
        let $name := $parameter/Name
        let $value := $parameter/Value
        where $name = "RENDER_FORMAT" or $name = RenderFormat"
        return data($value)'),
  EmailSubject = ExtensionSettings.query('
        for $parameter in /ParameterValues/ParameterValue
        let $name := $parameter/Name
        let $value := $parameter/Value
        where $name = "Subject"
        return data($value)'),
  ExtensionSettings
FROM S
```

Comment: This could do with some optimization: for example `FileSharePath = ExtensionSettings.query('/ParameterValues/ParameterValue[Name[text() = "PATH"]]/Value/text()` and if you only want a single value out of that then you should use `.value` instead of `.query`